# How to most concisely initialize variables to 0?

Tags: c++, c, variables, initialization

Let's say that we want to declare three integers, `p`, `q`, and `r`. Best practice is to initialize them to 0. The **C** way of doing this is:

```
int p, q, r;
p = q = r = 0;
```

The **C++** way of doing this is

```
int p(0), q(0), r(0);
```

In C, things are nice and tight; 0 is only used once. In contrast, the C++ call requires 0 to be repeated three times--once for each variable. A bit verbose.

Is there a more concise way of initializing variables using the C++ method, or is the initial value required for each variable declaration?

Also, any problem mixing the C-style initialization with C++ code? Thx :^)

EDIT: Fixed code to compile properly. Now, it takes two lines to declare and initialize the variables, so the question isn't very good, but I will leave it here for posterity. Hopefully helps someone.

Comment: "Best practice is to initialize them to 0." --> "Best practice is to initialize them".  Disagree about the "to 0" part.

Comment: If they are related, you probably want create a struct/class. Else you probably want to initialize with initial value (which is not necessary `0`).

Comment: In my experience, best practice would be a) better variable names and b) one initialization per line.

Comment: Try this: `int p{}, q{}, r{};`.

Comment: @KerrekSB try this ... if you want to fail code review ;-)

Comment: There are many different styles, and not a single correct answer.  I like to have variables initialized with the same value all together on the line where they are declared, e.g. `int p = 0, q = 0, r = 0;`

Comment: They didn't remove the "C way" of doing it from C++

Comment: The "C way of doing this" is `int p = 0, q = 0, r = 0;` or even `int p = { 0 }, q = { 0 }, r = { 0 };` (using the `= { 0 }` idiom). I have no idea why you replaced initialization with assignment and called it "C way of doing this". There's no tradition of replacing initialization with assignment in C (aside from some foced situations caused by limitations of C89/90). Never use assignment when you can use initialization.

Comment: And, as @chux correctly noted, best practice is to give variables *meaningful* initializers instead of dummy temporary ones. One can even argue that it is better idea to leave variables uninitialized than to perform a cargo-cult-style initialization with a dummy value.

Comment: `p = q = r = 0` is perfectly valid C++ code.

Comment: Note that `int p; p = 0;` is **not** initialization with 0; it's initialization to an unspecified value followed by **assignment** with 0. That difference is minor for builtin types, but it's extremely important for user-defined types. Consider the case where a class has no default constructor but has a constructor that takes int: `myClass m; m = 0;` is ill-formed, but `myClass m = 0;` is okay.

Answer (score 8):

> Best practice is to initialize them to 0.

This may be even harmful, as it would silence the compiler's protection. Consider following code:

```
 int p, q, r;
 p = q = r = 0;

 // ...

 p = FIRST_INDEX;
 r = LAST_INDEX;    // ups, we forget to initialize q with some real value

 // ...
 doSomething(p, q, r);
```

Normally, you will get a warning like:

> warning: 'q' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

but since the `q` is already intialized, the compiler thinks that is fine.

#### Intermixing declarations with code

If you have C++ or at least C99-conformant compiler, then one may argue, that code could be designed better, by moving variables' declarations *closest* to their first usage:

```
// some executable code

int p = FIRST_INDEX;
int q = LAST_INDEX;
int r = getSampleCoefficient();

doSomething(p, q, r);
```

This way, the issue presented in previous example may be avoided completely, since there is no gap between declarations and actual code.

---

You may use `p = q = r = 0;` in C++, it's just matter of coding style.

Comment: Are you suggesting that variables be left uninitialized until a meaningful value is available? At least two of my professors that it is best practice and defensive coding to initialize variables to 0 when declared.

Comment: @kmiklas: That's correct, a modern compiler will tell you, that variable is uninitialized. However, the best practice would be to declare these variables _closest_ to their first usage (which is allowed in C since C99 and in C++ since always).